# How do I pass in a python pandas.Dataframe object as an argument to a celery task?

Tags: python, django, pandas, celery

I would like to pass a pandas dataframe object as an argument to a celery task. Is there a way I can achieve this? I understand that dataframe objects are not JSON serializable and therefore cannot be used as arguments based on my current setup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like I can use the `pandas.Dataframe.to_json()` method to convert a given dataframe to JSON to begin with. Once I pass the JSON value to my celery task, I can use the `pd.read_json()` method to get back my `pandas.Dataframe` object.

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

[2] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 1):

`to_json` didn't work for me, it automatically tried to parse strings as datetimes so my result was invalid.

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize celery result, so something similar. [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) works for me.

```
df_as_dict = df.to_dict()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_as_dict)
```